# What is the best C++ Mail library used to read EML file / Outlook MSG file?

Tags: c++, email

We have to develop an in-house mail app. Please let me know what the best CPP library used to read EML file and Outlook MSG file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EML is basically the same as MHT; it's a plain text format which you can parse yourself, and I believe the WebBrowser control can also display the contents of an EML/MHT.

MSG is a binary MAPI format. You can use the MAPI libraries to deal with these (Windows only). For more information on how to deal with that, see [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx?display=Print).

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/outlook-converter) seems to be a suitable tool for conversion. Propriety formats (regardless from what vendor) are a pest. RCF822 Multi-Part MIME (which is what you find usually in EML files) rulez!